# How do I attach my table with others in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I an new to Laravel. I want like this:

[image]

When I store data that is storing correctly in multiple tables. After storing it will also have the id of all three tables on disease_symptoms_medicines table (foreignkeys). I not know how to do it.

In this code there is no error.

Here is my migrations:

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateDiseasesTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('diseases', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name')->nullable();
                $table->string('slug')->nullable();
                $table->text('description')->nullable();
                $table->text('symptoms')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('diseases');
        }
    }
```

Symptom migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('symptoms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Medicine migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('diseases', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->text('symptoms')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Created for foreign keys  to attach Disease, Symptoms and Medicine

Disease Model

```
    class Disease extends Model
    {
protected $table ='diseases';
public function symptoms(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Symptoms');
}
public function medicines(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Medicine');
}
```

Symptom Model

```
class Symptoms extends Model{
    protected $table ='symptoms';
    public function diseases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Disease');
    }
}
```

Medicine Model

```
    class Medicine extends Model{
    protected $table ='medicines';
    public function diseases(){

    $this->hasMany('App\Disease');
}
}
```

Here is my controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $disease=new Disease;
    $disease->name=$request->input('name');
    $disease->slug=$request->input('slug');
    $disease->description=$request->input('description');
    $disease->save();
    $symptom=new Symptoms;
    $symptom->name=$request->input('symtom');
    $symptom->save();
    $medicine=new Medicine;
    $medicine->name = $request->input('medic');
    $$medicine->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: A thing to keep in mind; Try to give your models Singular names instead of plural. You've done so for ``Disease`` and ``Medicine`` but not for ``Symptoms``. Being consistent will make things a lot easier to manage later on.

Comment: ok I will do next time.

Comment: There were various spelling errors in your post, which is one thing, but your spelling errors are leaking into your code. You have a control called `symtom` but a model is spelled correctly - it has a 'p' in it. This discrepancy is another consistency problem that may cause you difficulty later on.

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error in your migrations, When using eloquent relations laravel looks for a default reference unless you overide it.

For instance

```
class Symptoms extends Model{
    protected $table ='symptoms';
    public function diseases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Disease');
    }
```

Laravel will go to the diseases table and look for symptoms_id

See [Eloquent relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

You need to put proper foreign keys for the relations to work

Change to this :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('diseases', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            //add the foreign key
            $table->integer('symptoms_id');
            $table->text('symptoms')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

To save the relations  see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: i tried but nothing happened still the same problem .

Comment: @Mkamran: if you want more help, you will need to be helpful. You are the eyes and ears on the problem, so try to be as fulsome and verbose as possible when replying. Consider any answer on Stack Overflow as a starting point for your own research, rather than something that can be typed in verbatim. What more information can you provide to Lupyana to help them help you?

Comment: @Mkamran You should do the same for the other models, i.e Symptom, Medicine and Disease Models. You need proper relations or they won't work. What error are you getting? How are you calling the relations? Perhaps that will give me insight to your problem